# Prometheus gauge did not change value - Spring boot

Tags: java, spring-boot, prometheus, micrometer

I have spring boot app with soap client that is checking is some app is alive.
If the app is alive i am setting the gauge to 1 otherwise i am setting it to 0.
The problem is when i start the app and i send the request and the response is ok i see in prometheus that the gauge value is 1, but when i stop the server and i send another request i expect that the gauge value should be 0 but it is 1 again.

Here is my code. I have tried with atomic integer too but still problems.

```
 @Autowired
 MeterRegistry meterRegistry;


  public void callWebService() throws IOException {

String request = "message";
List<String> list = convertUsingJava8(url);
for (String string : list) {
  // AtomicInteger n = meterRegistry.gauge(string, new AtomicInteger(0));
  // Gauge shit = Gauge.build().name(string).help("shit").register();
  StringEntity stringEntity;
  stringEntity = new StringEntity(request, "UTF-8");
  stringEntity.setChunked(true);
  HttpPost httpPost = new HttpPost(string);
  httpPost.setEntity(stringEntity);
  try (CloseableHttpClient httpClient = HttpClientBuilder.create().build()) {
    HttpResponse response = null;
    response = httpClient.execute(httpPost);
    StringBuilder total = getMessage(response);
    System.out.println(total.toString());
    if (total.toString().contains("true")) {
      // shit.set(1.0);
      // meterRegistry.counter(string).increment();
      meterRegistry.gauge(string, 1);
      // n.getAndSet(1);
      // System.out.println(n);
      // meterRegistry.gauge(string, 1);
    }
  } catch (IOException e) {
    System.gc();
    meterRegistry.gauge(string, 0);
    // shit.set(0.0);
    // n.getAndSet(0);
    // System.out.println(n);
    // meterRegistry.gauge(string, 0);
    e.getMessage();
  }
}

}
```

Comment: Shouldn't you also set it to 0 when return code is error or if content does not contain true ?

Comment: after the `if (total.toString().contains("true"))` there is no else statement setting the gauge.

Comment: It is in the catch so when the app goes to catch it is set to 0. But nothing changes.

Comment: I have the same problem!

Comment: I did not found any solution about that so i fixed it with using this:
<dependency>
   <groupId>io.prometheus</groupId>
   <artifactId>simpleclient</artifactId>
   <version>0.6.0</version>
  </dependency>